# Clutter Script connect signals gives ValueError

Tags: python, clutter

I'm trying to make a clutter ui using python.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import Clutter, ClutterGst
import sys

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        script = Clutter.Script.new()
        script.load_from_file("mainwindow.json")
        stage = script.get_object("main-stage")
        script.connect_signals(stage)
        stage.show_all()

def main():
    ClutterGst.init(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    Clutter.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here is mainwindow.json

```
{
"id": "main-stage",
"type": "ClutterStage",
"signals": [
    {
        "name": "destroy",
        "handler": "clutter_main_quit"
    }
]
}
```

However, it gives an error when the connect_signals method is called:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "main.py", line 15, in main
    main = MainWindow()
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    script.connect_signals(stage)
ValueError: Pointer arguments are restricted to integers, capsules, and None. See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683599
```

I am successful if I just exclude the connect_signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect_signals()` method is not introspectable because it assumes that all the callable symbols are going to be resolved via `dlsym()`, which is something that only works in C.

For interpreted languages, and languages that perform name mangling on the symbols, you will have to use the `connect_signals_full()` method, and pass a function that can resolve the signal handler name as used in the UI description data into a callable object.

For instance, you could reuse the code that the `Gtk` override inside pygobject uses to implement the same functionality: https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/gi/overrides/Gtk.py#n441

Comment: Just as a followup: I updated pyclutter to ship introspection overrides for pygobject, including the code above. This means that ClutterScript signal connection should now work if you use pyclutter from master.